# How to use "Replace in selection" in Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to understand how to reliably / consistently use the  `Replace in Selection` in `Intellij`.

- Highlight some text
- Command-R for `Find/Replace in file`

The surprise is that the entire selected text is automatically thrown into the to-be-replaced entry field in the dialog:

[image]

My task is *not* that: it is to replace the single quotes **inside** that selected area with double quotes.  What are the correct step to do that?

[image]

I do know I have been able to do this in the past: but uncertain of what were done differently. I believe `Intellij-Idea` exhibits same behavior.  I am using `2019.2.X Ultimate` for both products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I found it. It's a  UI change in latest release.  `Pycharm` app has changed from having a

```
Replace in Selection
```

checkbox - which worked great for me - to having an inscrutable tiny icon in the dialog:

[image]

By the way for keyboarders you can select this by hitting `CMD-R` *again*.  At least they did preserve a way to do it by keyboarding.

Comment: Double Ctrl+R works for me.

Comment: @NikolayProkopyev I presume you're on Windows?

Comment: no, Arch Linux.

Comment: @NikolayProkopyev Control-R does nothing for me [on mac] thus my question

Comment: I like coming back to my own questions years later for something arcane like this that had fallen out of the memory banks.